# What is the best method to update NoOfStudents of each department in Departments table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database

I just started learning MSSQL and encountered such an exercise. Please give me a solution to solve it

Ex: Update NoOfStudents of each department in Departments table where NoOfStudents is the total number of
students of each departments. Note that for department that has no student, the NoOfStudents should be 0.

Table: Departments

```
DeptID
Name
NoOfStudents
```

Table: Students

```
StudentID
LastName
FirstName
Sex
DateOfBirth
PlaceOfBirth
DeptID
Scholarship
AverageScore
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You won't learn anything if someone just gives the answer.

Comment: *Don't* store the statistics in the departments table, calculate it whenever you need it with a simple `select Count(*) ...`. Otherwise you'll always have a wrong answer, or introduce excessive blocking

Comment: The solution your instructor expects is based on the recent topics you have covered in your course. So what are those topics? Did they include aggregates? At a minimum, you should be able to write a simple select query that calculates the number of students per department. Once you have that working, you can then address the update logic. Make an effort - you won't learn anything by asking others for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the update query like below. The **Count** Always Return Zero if nothing Found

`update Departments set NoOfStudents=(select count(1) from Students s where s.DeptID=Departments.DeptID)`

Comment: Without triggers and transactions, this guarantees the value will always be wrong. With a trigger, it will introduce excessive locking. Storing a count in the `Department` is the wrong approach to begin with